# network operation without asyncTask in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I successfully can connect to my servlet server using AsyncTask, but now i decided that i would like to have a progress dialog letting the user know that there is a network operation in progress. (using 2G and sometimes 3G i can notice the delay in fetching the results).
My problem started when AsyncTask crashed when tried to do this:

```
private class GetQinfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String> {
            ProgressDialog progDailog ;
             protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    progDailog= new ProgressDialog(GetTicket.this);
                    progDailog.setMessage("pls wait");
                    progDailog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    progDailog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    progDailog.setCancelable(true);
                    progDailog.show();
                }    
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {...}
        protected void onPostExecute(String branchQ){
         ...
         progDailog.dismiss();
        }
}
```

But this gave me an exception

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

So i decided to stop using AsyncTask, since i dont really need it( I think). Since i am not allowing the user to do anything on the UI, is there a point in using AsyncTask?
I went for the threading solution:

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
             String line=null;
             try {
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("command", "GetQ"));
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city));
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type));
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("org", org));
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("branch", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"utf-8"));

                 // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();
                BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);
                InputStream is = buf.getContent();
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

              line = r.readLine();
               nameValuePairs.clear();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                line="-1";
            }

            String[] info=line.split(";");
            if(info[1].equals("-1")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                 ....
                //Update the UI
                 }
          }
          }).start();
```

But for some reason this threw a  java.net.SocketException: Socket closed on this line
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
any ideas? Thanks

EDIT:
@Ahmad Dwaik 'Warlock'
I do call it from the main thread, i have a spinner and a method

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
             int arg2, long arg3) {
       if(arg2==0){
            //no selection
            }
        else{
new GetQinfo().execute(city,type,org,spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
}
```

By executing this i get the java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() error. the log is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
12-07 10:16:19.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
12-07 10:16:19.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
12-07 10:16:19.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:109)
12-07 10:16:19.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:114)
12-07 10:16:19.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
12-07 10:16:19.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
12-07 10:16:19.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at com.example.quecustomer.GetTicket$GetQinfo.onPreExecute(GetTicket.java:872)
12-07 10:16:19.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
12-07 10:16:19.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
12-07 10:16:19.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at com.example.quecustomer.GetTicket$1.run(GetTicket.java:781)
12-07 10:16:19.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

GetTicket.java:872 is referring to this line:

```
 progDailog= new ProgressDialog(GetTicket.this);
```

my doInBackground:
@

```
Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                try {
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("command", "GetQ"));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", arg0[0]));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", arg0[1]));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("org", arg0[2]));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("branch", arg0[3]));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"utf-8"));
                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();
                    BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);
                    InputStream is = buf.getContent();
                    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                   String line = r.readLine();
                   nameValuePairs.clear();
                   return line;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
```

EDIT 2
It turns out i found a way round it, but not sure if it is correct. well it works, so it must be:)

I used onProgressUpdate(Void... none) to create the ProgressDialog and dismiss it on onPostExecute().
What do you make of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stack trace shows that you are calling the `AsyncTask` from another `Thread` here:

```
12-07 10:16:19.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at com.example.quecustomer.GetTicket$1.run(GetTicket.java:781)
12-07 10:16:19.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Look at line 781 of `GetTicket`. There you are probably calling `new GetQinfo.execute()` which takes you to:

```
12-07 10:16:19.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at com.example.quecustomer.GetTicket$GetQinfo.onPreExecute(GetTicket.java:872)
```

Comment: !! i am calling this AsyncTask from two different places. one is a thread and the other is from a thread. So what does that mean? i cant call a progress dialog from a thread calling an asynctask?

Comment: No, you cannot. You should call `AsyncTask` from the UI `Thread` only.

Answer (score 0):

About this error, which you didn't provide much details

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

it seems that you don't call your AsyncTask `new GetQinfo().execute(args);`  from within Main "UI" thread.

Consider using AsyncTask again, implement it well and call it directly from within main thread. if that didnt help show your full AsyncTask subclass and full logcat

Comment: Kindly post your doInBackground() implementation